# Get fields from a third model based on the foreign key of a second model

Tags: python, django

I have three models, one of which has an ID from each of the others to join them. The issue I am trying to solve is how I can get the values From table one into table three  using table two to join them in the serializer, or if that is even the approach I should be taking to begin with.

model

```
class ModelOne(models.Model):
    color = models.CharField()
    size = models.CharField()

class ModelTwo(models.Model):
    One_id = models.ForeignKey(ModelOne)
    Three_id = models.CharField()

class ModelThree(models.Model):
```

example serializer

```
class ModelThree Serializer
    model = ModelThree
    fields = ('color', 'size')

def get_color(self, obj):
    ???

def get_size(self, obj):
    ???
```

my db structure

```
        ModelOne
-------------------------------------
id  color   size

    ModelTwo
-------------------------------------
id  ModelOneID  ModelThreeID

    ModelThree
-------------------------------------
id
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't get it yet but you have: list id of Model 1 right?

~> You want to have model 3 (query by model2)

```
# The flow: models2.objects.filter(model1_id__in = md1_ids)
# And you want to get model3 ? ~> need ids to query
# ~> Query 1: 
md3_ids = models2.objects.filter(model1_id__in = md1_ids).values_list("model3_id", flat="true")
md3 = Models3.objects.filter(pk__in md3_ids)
```

Is this it? I don't know what you want...

Comment: essentially yes, I am trying to get the fields from model 1 into model 3, but they are only joined on model 2. I have only been using django for about 2 weeks and I can't find much information on this

Comment: Sure, no link so join.. if you want to create a special view (just view) you can use View type models to create new models. Or you can use Raw query...

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you have two models `ModelOne` and `ModelThree` which are joined by another model `ModelTwo`

```
class ModelOne(models.Model):
    color = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    size = models.CharField(max_length=200)


class ModelTwo(models.Model):
    one = models.ForeignKey(ModelOne)
    three = models.ForeignKey('ModelThree')


class ModelThree(models.Model):
    some_field = models.CharField(max_length=200)

# this looks like a ManyToMany relationship between ModelThree and ModelOne
# where ModelTwo is the intermediate model 
# you may want to check the docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/models/#many-to-many-relationships
```

and you want to be able to query values from ModelOne into ModelThree.

If you have an instance of ModelThree m3, then you can get all related ModelOne instances by querying the other side of the [foreignkey relation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/relations/) like so:

```
# ex:  m3 = ModelThree.objects.first()
model_twos = m3.modeltwo_set.all()
for two in model_twos:
   print two.one.color, two.one.size
```